# Bad typing hint in python

Tags: python, class, typing

I have a variable, let's call it some_variable. Then I have "interface" which tells me, what method should be used in classes:

```
class InterfaceClass:
    def method_a(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
    def method_b(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

class A(InterfaceClass):
    
    def method_a(self):
       return 1
    def method_b(self):
        return 0

class B(InterfaceClass):
    
    def method_a(self):
       return 0
    def method_b(self):
        return 1
```

And in other class I have something like this:

```
someType = TypeVar("SomeType", A, B)
class SOmeClass:
    def __init__(self, some_class: Type[someType]):
        some_variable: someType = some_class

SOmeClass(B)
```

The question is. How to type it properly? Because this solution is not acceptable for me. The problem is, that when I will write some_variable.method_a(), and I will click to method_a, my IDE will redirect me to the first class of the TypeVar statement -> a.method_a(). Basically, IDE points to class A. How to force my IDE to show a dropdown to choose what class I'm looking for? Or better, how to tell my IDE, that I passed to SOmeClass "B"?

Comment: Is `some_variable: someType = some_class` supposed to be `some_variable: someType = some_class()`?

Comment: Yes, it is some_class(), forgot to write it in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `Generic` in `SomeClass` fixes your issue, as then the IDE knows to point to class B. This is also conventional - if you're using TypeVar inside a class it should be referenced in a Generic inheritance structure. Full example here:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


class InterfaceClass:
    def method_a(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
    def method_b(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

class A(InterfaceClass):
    def method_a(self):
       return 1
    def method_b(self):
        return 0

class B(InterfaceClass):
    def method_a(self):
       return 0
    def method_b(self):
        return 1
    
SomeType = TypeVar("SomeType", A, B)
class SomeClass(Generic[SomeType]): # Critical difference here
    def __init__(self, some_class: type[SomeType]):
        self.some_variable: SomeType = some_class()

x = SomeClass(B)
x.some_variable.method_b()
```